# Rename the link in .dll (relink, Windows)

Tags: windows, dll, linker

On Windows 10 I have a library `myLib.dll` which has a link to `python37.dll`.

I need to change the link name `python37.dll` to `python39.dll`.

Is it possible to do without rebuilding? If yes, please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a [hex-editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors). Change the string, just make sure it has the same length as the old string. Verify your change with [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Thank you! I changed the name. I haven't solved my original problem, but it answers the question :)